# Adding tensors along certain dimensions with Theano

Tags: python, theano, array-broadcasting

I am trying to understand how to use `dimshuffle` to broadcast noise to a 4 dimensional tensor. For example the 4 dimensional tensor has shape `(num_examples, 3, 32, 32)` where 3 corresponds to the r,g,b components of the 32*32 image. I want to add Gaussian noise, however I want to add the same noise to all the three components (i.e r,g,b) and for each example the noise would be a random 32*32 matrix.

So I have to add the two tensors of dimensions `(num_examples, 3, 32, 32)` and `(num_examples, 32, 32)`, respectively. I have not been able to figure out how to use `dimshuffle` on the second tensor so that its last two dimensions become broadcastable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dimshuffle`

```
x = T.tensor4() # Nx3x32x32
y = T.tensor3() # Nx32x32
z = y.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1, 2) + x
```